# Assign var to null to make two different queries

Tags: c#

Is there a way to assign var query without knowing the return type. I want to initialize var to null and then do either of two different kind of queries that return different custom objects without knowing beforehand which one. So I only have initialize a single query in a method.

The error I am getting is *"Cannot assign  to an implicitly-typed local variable"*. I tried to look up previous questions and answers, but don't understand why var cannot be assigned null. Isn't it supposed to be assigned later on to the object that is received? Is there a way around this using a more generic upper level object class that can handle this without knowing the return type?

```
var query = null;
if (condition) {
    query = /* something */
} 
else 
{
    query = /* something else */
}
```

Comment: " Isn't it supposed to be assigned later on to the object that is received?" - No, the type is inferred from the type of the second operand of the assignment operator. The `null` literal doesn't *have* a type, hence the problem.

Comment: If you're unsure what type will be assigned, consider using a Factory Pattern to initialize the type you need.

Comment: "level object class that can handle this without knowing the return type"
you could always do 
object query;. Though I would guess there is a better suited less generic object for your needs.

Comment: You _could_ use `dynamic`, then the type is resolved at runtime. But this sounds like a XY-problem, there is definitely a better way. If `query`  should hold different types consider to use two variables or a common parent-class/interface.

Answer (score 2):

`var` can't be assigned null because there's no type information in `null` to tell the compiler which type of null thing it is.  `var` is a compile-time thing--it's required to have a known type at compile time; it's just that the compiler can figure that type out from what you assign to it.